# Why const or let is not throwing an error before initialising value while using debugger (chrome)

Tags: javascript

As per ECMA, We should initialise the const / let before using it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const.

Below code is working as expected,

```
function sample(){
    console.log(color);
    const color = 'skyblue'
}
```

Below code is not working while debugging (Attached Screenshot - Refer Local section).
Not getting error as expected,
Follow the same code & call the sample() Fn,

```
function sample(){
    debugger;
    console.log(color);
    const color = 'skyblue'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. The error is correctly thrown on the line `console.log(color);` after the `debugger` statement.

Comment: Can you replicate it by having the same code inside the function & call the function.

Comment: I used the function with the debugger, called it, stepped to the next line and got an exception due to TDZ: "Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'color' before initialization"

Comment: Tried with different machine , it is intermediate issue. Getting error sometimes in debugger & sometimes not. Weird

Comment: Your screenshot has not yet step to the line with `console.log(color);`

Comment: But if you see  right side Local section: Color:undefined, Next step it's printing it as undefined. Ideally it should not show color itself, Since it is const.